# How to print dot pattern in correct way?

Tags: java

This is what I have.

when I omit one of the makePattern(size - 1) in makePattern(int size), I got the bottom half. But I don't know how to get the top half.

```
public void makePattern(int size){

    stringList = new ArrayList<String>();
    if (size == 0){
        System.out.print("");
    }
    else{

        makePattern(size - 1);
        System.out.println(dotString(size));
        makePattern(size - 1);

    }
}
```

Helper method

```
  public String dotString(int x){
    if (x == 1){
        return ".";
    }
    else{

        return dotString(x - 1) + ".";
    }
}
```

main method to test:

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {

    Pattern rP = new Pattern();

    int sizePt = 5;
    System.out.println();
    for(int i=1; i<=sizePt; i++) {
        System.out.println("pattern " + i);
        rP.makePattern(i);
        ArrayList<String> pattern = rP.getStringList();
        for(int j = 0; j < pattern.size() ; j++)
            System.out.println(pattern.get(j));

        System.out.println();
    }
```

The out put I get:

pattern 1

```
.
```

pattern 2

```
.

..

.
```

pattern 3

```
.

..

.

...

.

..

.
```

The output that I want is:

i.e. makePattern(3)

```
.

..

...

..

.
```

Comment: Do you need to do this recursively?

Comment: It's not directly relevant, but should be helpful: I wrote a [short debugging tutorial](http://keysersblog.wordpress.com/2014/04/21/debugging-java-code-a-beginners-guide/) for java beginners. The part about printing might help you understand the flow of your code.

Comment: "Please help" isn't a question. keyser's very polite suggestion of "learn how to debug" is probably the best possible help you could get right now. In general, there are much better debugging techniques than StackOverflow.

Comment: I want to do this recursively without loop.

Answer (score 2):

Every time you make a recursive call, you're making a full pattern each time.  This is not what you want.  Instead, you want to be making **half** of a pattern with each function call.  Either the top half or the bottom half.

---

So in the end you want a recursive function that does this:

```
.  
..  
...
```

and a recursive function that does this(it's possible to do both with the same function)

```
...
..
.
```

and a function to tie them together.

---

Another approach you can take is to only have one recursive call per function.

Make a function that prints variants on this pattern

```
...
....
.....
....
...
```

and then call it like this

```
makePattern(**insert args here**)
{
    //handle base case
    System.out.println(dotString(size));
    makePattern(**insert args here**)
    System.out.println(dotString(size));
}
```

Comment: @Pshemo oops, i've added psudocode.  Do i still get the +1?

Comment: I don't know how to start the other half

Comment: @user3792115 you would make both directly from the main method, or from a non-recursive helper function

Answer (score 0):

My 2 cents:

```
public void makePattern(int size, int direction)
{
    if (size == 0)
        return; // quit recursion when we're down to 0

    // start out recursively calling back until we reach 0 with -1 direction
    // that will print AFTER the calls to the negative direction so the last
    // recursive call prints FIRST
    if (direction <= 0)
        makePattern(size - 1, -1);

    // all the makePatterns and prints for the lower direction will happen
    // and return back to here where we call print for the original number
    // passed
    System.out.println(dotString(size));

    // now we recursively call with direction = 1 AFTER printing so the last
    // recursive call prints LAST
    if (direction >= 0)
        makePattern(size - 1, 1);
}
```